# Getting error "Need to acknowledge to Apple's Apple ID and Privacy statement."

Tags: app-store-connect, fastlane, fastlane-match, fastlane-deliver, fastlane-pilot

Hi we're getting this error when using fastlane sigh/get_provisioning_profile. I don't think it is a [fastlane issue](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/18098) as it happened before [case1](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/12675) [case2](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/12577) and got fixed by accepting the agreement or other unknown reason..

> Need to acknowledge to Apple's Apple ID and Privacy statement. Please manually log into https://appleid.apple.com (or https://appstoreconnect.apple.com) to acknowledge the statement.

We went to

- https://appleid.apple.com
- https://appstoreconnect.apple.com
- https://itunesconnect.apple.com

but there's nothing to approve there.

Any ideas?

Comment: Facing the same issue, nothing to accept on appstore connect.

Comment: me too... same issue and nothing to accept. maybe we need to set up 2fa

Comment: We've got the same issue, it seems we have a new agreement to sign for paid apps (even though our app is free).

Comment: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/18098 Just for reference, the same issue is discussed on the fastlane github page.

Answer (score 35):

## Summary:

## Case 1:

### * You don't want 2FA enabled

1. Update Gemfile with [fastlane 2.173.0](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/releases/tag/2.173.0) and run `bundle install`, `bundle update fastlane`, or `bundle update`
2. Use `SPACESHIP_SKIP_2FA_UPGRADE=1` in your CI

## Case 2:

### * You have 2FA enabled

### * You only need non-enterprise account

1. Generate `APP_STORE_CONNECT_API_KEY` from [appstore connect](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/access/api) using an [Account Holder role](https://medium.com/wandercodes/which-app-store-connect-role-do-you-need-e1e1a69ec368).

[image]

It looks like

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nabcdef12345abcdef12345\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

2. Add it to your CI as APP_STORE_CONNECT_API_KEY environment variable

- 

```
lane :get_app_store_connect_api_key do
  ensure_env_vars(
    env_vars: [
      'APP_STORE_CONNECT_API_KEY'
    ]
  ) 
  app_store_connect_api_key(
    key_id: "12345ABCDEF",
    issuer_id: "1234abcd-12ab-12ab-12ab-123456abcdef",
    key_content: "#{ENV["APP_STORE_CONNECT_API_KEY"]}".gsub('\n', '\\n'),
    in_house: false,
  )
end
```

3. Pass it to your lanes

- 

```
get_provisioning_profile(api_key: get_app_store_connect_api_key)

sigh(api_key: get_app_store_connect_api_key)

pilot(api_key: get_app_store_connect_api_key)
```

## Case 3:

### * You have 2FA enabled

### * You need enterprise account and fetch profiles

1. Run

```
fastlane spaceauth -u user@email.com
```

2. Use the output as `FASTLANE_SESSION` environment variable on your CI.
3. You still need to include `FASTLANE_PASSWORD`

Note that this only lasts for **8 hours**

## Case 4:

### * You have 2FA enabled

### * You need enterprise or non-enterprise account

### * You need to upload to appstore

1. Create FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD from https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage
2. Set it as environment variable in your ci

## Case 5:

### * You have 2FA enabled

### * You need to download dsyms from appstore connect

1. Run

```
fastlane spaceauth -u user@email.com
```

2. Use the output as `FASTLANE_SESSION` environment variable on your CI.
3. You still need to include `FASTLANE_USER` and `FASTLANE_PASSWORD`

Note that this only lasts for **8 hours**

Comment: Nice explanation! Do you also have a solution for when I need download_dsyms ? I have 2FA enabled accidentially 

Comment: Hi @blackjacx I added it as case 5

Comment: Is it normal to use app_store_connect_api_key and fastlane to prompt me for apple userID and password? I thought that I am using the api key in order to avoid 2FA.

Comment: For upload_to_testflight, no username required

Comment: hmm.. looks like its sending 2FA on pem action. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: @PoppyAnc can you try case 5 for pem as well?

Comment: @PoppyAnc nope this should not happen

Comment: I'm not able to get pass this problem.  I've added the spaceship reference into my fastlane file and I've created my app store connect key and added it into my fastlane teams connection setting for the app and then triggered a new build but it still fails.  Any help much appreciated, what am I missing?  Thank you

Comment: Hey @Jack note that you don't need FASTLANE_PASSWORD when you are using the api key. You may contact me in https://www.linkedin.com/in/gonzalezted/ lets debug it

Comment: Thanks Ted, I've sent you an email!

Comment: Thanks @Ted, I had to use both #5 for pem and #2 for pilot!

Answer (score 22):

I had the same exact issue using [Bitrise](https://www.bitrise.io/) (another CI/CD tool). The error message was misleading because it wasn't related to accepting some new policies, but to the **new authentication system** used by the [App Store Connect API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/creating_api_keys_for_app_store_connect_api).

To fix the issue I logged in Bitrise and I had to switch to the new authentication method as shown in the image below.

[image]

The old auth method was based on the credentials of a single Apple Developer user, the new method instead is based on the generation of an API Key. As you see from the screenshot below, I had to create an API key under **User and Access -> Keys** and then upload it to Bitrise.

[image]

I hope my case can help someone else to fix the issue. I am pretty sure you have to follow more or less the same procedure even if you're using a different tool.

Comment: thanks for sharing.. Just a question was your bitrise build failing at the auto provision step or later at the itunes connect deployment step?

Comment: @VMA92 at the Auto Provision step. Indeed I had to change it to its "new" version as the Bitrise documentation is saying here: https://devcenter.bitrise.io/getting-started/configuring-bitrise-steps-that-require-apple-developer-account-data/

Answer (score 10):

I was experiencing it with an Apple account to authenticate and authorize the fastlane actions.

Changing my CI to use [Apple API key](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/creating_api_keys_for_app_store_connect_api) seems to solve the issue.

Fasltane should use `app_store_connect_api_key`

Here the docs:
http://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/app_store_connect_api_key/#app_store_connect_api_key

Answer (score 9):

Have you checked your 2FA settings?

Apple announced that: "Starting February 2021, additional authentication will be required for all users to sign in to App Store Connect."

Comment: No, it explains why the problem arose and that the message presented is incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

For Azure DevOps users a temporary `SPACESHIP_SKIP_2FA_UPGRADE=1` works while we wait for AppStoreConnect Api key support to be merged:

> https://github.com/microsoft/app-store-vsts-extension/pull/189

[image: spaceship skip 2FA upgrade]

---

EDIT

---

Pull request has been merged and API authentication now works and is the preferred way to authenticate.

[image: AppStoreConnect API authentication]

Answer (score 3):

For those, who using [Pilot](http://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/pilot/#pilot) there is a simple solution:

Just add this to Pilot:

```
skip_waiting_for_build_processing: true,
apple_id: "123456789"
```

You can find apple_id on AppStoreConnect in General > App information

Reference:
https://dev.to/dumazy/upload-to-testflight-with-fastlane-and-2fa-11k8

Comment: @prapin can you take a look at my solution "upload_ip"a in the below section and it worked for me successfully. Let us know for any help

Comment: @Gangadhar Yes, I did today something similar to your solution, with a JSON file referred from `Fastfile` by `api_key_path`, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the following solution worked for uploading the ipa files

```
lane :upload_ipa do |options|
  api_key = app_store_connect_api_key(
    key_id: "xxxxx",
    issuer_id: "xxxxxx",
    key_filepath: "./fastlane/AuthKey_xxxxx.p8", #Mention the relative path
    duration: 1200, # optional
    in_house: false, # optional but may be required if using match/sigh
  )
  # The ipa and team_id are sent as options parameters to the method
  pilot(api_key: api_key, 
    ipa: options[:ipa],
    team_id: options[:team_id],
        skip_waiting_for_build_processing: true,
    wait_processing_interval: 120,
         app_platform: options[:app_platform])
end
```